# What's the difference between @file_put_contents() and file_put_contents()?

Tags: php

I've come across some PHP that triggers `file_put_contents()` as follows:

`@file_put_contents($path_name_to_write_to, $string);`

What's the significance of `@` before the function call - if any? How is this different from `file_put_contents($path_name_to_write_to, $string);` - if at all?

Thanks.

Comment: `@` is an error-suppression operator. The functions are the same.

Comment: Ah, of course. Apologies about the duplicate post. Google is really bad for picking up for searches for '@ symbol PHP'. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PHP manual: "PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored."

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 1):

As per the doc:

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression   in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

<kbd>[documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)</kbd>